# External Validation of Prediction Models - Cox vs Logistic Regression, pros and cons?

Tags: logistic, cox-model, validation

I have made a Cox PH model for prognostication of a favourable outcome (with competing events being death). I now have an independent set of data to do external validation on this model. The primary purpose of the model is risk stratification.

As I have read, I could construct a Prognosis Index using the linear predictor of the Cox PH model, then assess discrimination and calibration, as stated by Royston & Altman (BMC 2013). My question with this approach is: is there a way to construct a ROC curve, using this approach? Second queston is, Royston & Altman suggested using risk groups and KM curve to evaluate model discrimination and calibration, however, in the setting of competing events, I would be using cumulative incidence curves. Therefore, does the approach which they specify also work for CIFs? Finally, can you suggest some R codes and packages that will work for this approach?

Alternatively, I could re-derive my prognosis model to a logistic regression model with IPCW. I believe this will allow me to perform validation and derive a ROC/AUC. My question is, do I need to do anything about censoring or competing events in the validation dataset?

Your insight is much appreciated!